# generate numbered list of computer-name's without foreach in powershell

Tags: powershell, range, computer-name

Just wondering if there way a way to generate a numbered list of computers like this without using foreach, so that Don Jones would like me:

```
1..3 | foreach { "COMPUTER0$_" }
```

The output looks like:

```
 COMPUTER01
 COMPUTER02
 COMPUTER03
```

I'm surprised you can't use a script parameter:

```
1..3 | write-output { write-output "COMPUTER0$_" }
```

EDIT:

Actually, you can use a script block with any parameter that reads the pipe, so to me foreach is kind of a place holder for a script block:

```
1..3 | write-output -inputobject { "COMPUTER0$_" }
```

And here's a way to pad zeros:

```
1..24 | write-output -inputobject { 'computer{0:d2}' -f $_ }
```

The answer from the comments:

```
1..3 -replace '^','COMPUTER0'
```

Here's another way to pad the zeros, but with the short version of foreach and the integer version of .tostring():

```
1..100 | % tostring COMP000
```

Comment: Why would you want to not use foreach? Is this homework?

Comment: Often in powershell you can pipe in a list of objects or specify a list as a parameter.  And it makes Don Jones die a little inside:  http://windowsitpro.com/blog/foreach-makes-me-die-little-inside

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't read the error message or `Get-Help Write-Output` If you want it simple use `1..3 -replace '^','COMPUTER0'`

Comment: That's a good one.  I didn't even realize the replace operator could work on a list.

Comment: I figured this one out for piping to new-adcomputer under a 'name' property:

    `1..3 | select @{name='name'; expression = {"computer0$_"}}`